# Profiling/optimising heavily multithreaded application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm writing a performance-critical .NET application which makes heavy use of multithreading.

Using the Visual Studio performance profiler, the top functions with Exclusive samples are:

`WaitHandle.WaitAny()` - 14.23%

`@JIT_MonReliableEnter@8` - 7.76%

`Monitor.Enter` - 5.09%

Basically, my top 3 functions are working with threading primitives and out of my control to some extent I believe.  My work/processing routines are pretty small in comparison and I'm trying to increase performance.  I believe the algorithms involved are pretty sound, although I am reviewing them fairly frequently.

My questions are:

- If there are 14.23% of CPU samples in these methods - is the CPU effectively 'idle' for most of those samples, i.e. just waiting on other threads?  Or is the idle part of the thread-waits not shown as a part of the profile trace [and the 27.08% shown in these 3 the sum of all overhead within those sync methods]?  (I can guess that this is mostly idle, but would appreciate some decent reference material behind answers to this one please)
- I have reviewed my locking schemes, however do these results indicate some particular bottleneck or technique I should look into for further optimisation?
- Is `WaitAny` quite poor in particular?  I use it heavily to check whether particular queue objects are readable/writable, but also checking an abort flag at the same time.  Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: It could be the way you _use_ those primitives.

Comment: @Henk - indeed, I tried to allude to that by saying in reviewing my algorithms, locking schemes

Comment: @KierenJohnstone If you have VS 2010, it's probably better to use the Concurrency Profiler/Visualizer for this.

Comment: I used the concurrency profiler/visualizer, the textual/data results showed me contentions and handle numbers .. which I didn't see as useful, or a graph of thread execution .. which didn't seem useful either.  Maybe I need to think of some way of using it, but even in this work-heavy multithreaded app, it seems like a flashy feature that doesn't give much insight..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your CPU isn't necessarily idle when a thread is in a `WaitHandle.WaitAny` or a `Monitor.Enter`. A *thread* that's in a wait is idle, but presumably other threads are busy executing. This is especially true of `Monitor.Enter`. If a thread is blocked on a lock, then one would hope the thread that has that lock is executing code rather than sitting idle.

Also, if your thread is using the `WaitAny` to read from a queue, then it's likely that the queue simply doesn't have anything in it. That's not a performance problem for the consumer code. It just means that the producer isn't putting things into the queue fast enough. Now, that might be because the producer is slow, or because data isn't coming in fast enough.

If you're processing data faster than it can come in, then it doesn't look like you have a performance problem. Certainly not on the consumer side.

As far as using `WaitAny` for queuing, I would suggest that you use [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) and the methods that take a cancellation token, like [TryAdd(T, Int32, CancellationToken)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381943.aspx). Converting to cancellation tokens really simplified my multi-threaded queuing code.

Comment: Thanks I'll check out that collection for sure.  In terms o overall CPU use I know when a thread is waiting others may be busy, any idea though if the samples captured there all count as the thread they were captures in being idle, or are the recorded samples .net overhead and not time spent 'waiting'?

Comment: Also, I am doing the production as well as consumption.  The production code was included in this profile trace.  I would then expect to see the production code near the top then - ???

Comment: @Kieren: If a sample shows a thread idle (in a `WaitAny` or `Monitor.Enter`), then I would expect that it really is idle. One would expect that any profiling overhead would be removed from the stats. As far as what you would expect to see, I don't know enough about your application to say. The producer might be idle, too, if it's waiting for data from a network stream or a disk file or something.

Comment: thanks, that part is crucial - according to you WaitAny and Monitor.Enter samples are idle cycles, but according to Igor profiling stats do not include idle cycles, and so what's sampled is overhead in those methods (note: not profiling overhead, but internal .NET threading code that for example puts it into the wait state).  Do you have a source / reference for that part?

Comment: (Your link to BlockingCollection links to the Task class btw ;))

Comment: I've looked over the source of `BlockingCollection`, and read up on `SpinWait`, `SpinLock`s, `SemaphoreSlim`s etc.. it seems that `BlockingCollection` with a bounded capacity and the default `ConcurrentQueue` container is exactly what I should try.  Thanks.  If you have an update as to why you think the profiler would show idle cycles on the trace that would be great.

Comment: Switching to a `BlockingCollection` resulted in an average 22% speed increase, and 56% boost in CPU use (was about ~20% CPU, now about ~30% CPU).  Which is good all around I think :)

Answer (score 4):

The profiling statistics **do not** include the time when threads were blocked.

The sampling-based profiler basically asks each core to report back after every X (say 1,000,000) non-idle cycles. Each time a core reports back, the profiler remembers the current call stack. The profiling results are reconstructed from the call stacks that the profiler recorded.

From the profiling results, you know that 14.23% of the time a core was doing work, it was executing the instructions in WaitHandle.WaitAny. If your program is CPU-bound, optimizing the WaitAny part (e.g., using a different primitive) could have a significant impact on the performance. However, if the program is *not* CPU-bound and spends the majority of its time waiting on a server, disk, another process or some other external input, then optimizing the WaitAny-related code will not be very useful.

So, your next step should be figuring out what is the CPU utilization of your program. Also, note the Concurrency Visualizer that Ilian mentioned can be useful to understand how the threads in your program spend their time.

Comment: The program as a whole uses ~70% CPU, I will look into the WaitAny alternatives such as BlockingCollection Jim speaks about.

Comment: Hey Kieren, any updates on this one? how did you improved your CPU consumption eventually?